# Svn in Eclipse Error running context

Tags: eclipse, svn

when I want commit, branch/tag switch with repository in eclipse I receive this message

```
org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: APR does not understand this error code
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'url'
svn: Error running context: An error occurred during SSL communication
```

I can check out browse my repository . I can commit by tortoise but in eclipse it doesnt work. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I just  encounter this problem.
Please check you SVN properties.Ensure you SVN interface is SVNkit.
Maybe can help you.

Comment: sounds more like a commentary than an answer to me